# stored Proc issue when copying database

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Currently attemping to use a storedproc in SQL Server for the very first time...

Right now we have a simple stored proc that creates a copy of a database that we will use for our CMS installations.

We have the stored proc working quite well, provided the variables are all hardcoded into the script.

All we need to do is apply 1 variable into the storedproc however everytime we try to run it, it generates errors stating that the scalar variable @dsource is not defined.

Im also not too sure how to apply variables as parts of strings in stored procs so any help greatly appreciated

basically we need to define the @dsource parameter and use it within the string so we can change the required directory paths with this particular variable.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      
-- Create date: 
-- Description: 
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE one_installer
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @dsource
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
BACKUP DATABASE base_db 
     TO DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\base_db.bak' WITH FORMAT
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\base_db.bak'
RESTORE DATABASE @dsource 
   FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\base_db.bak'
   WITH 
   MOVE 'base_db' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\' dsource '.mdf',
   MOVE 'base_db_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\'  dsource  '_log.ldf'
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify, as everything is hardcoded, just declare 2 more local variables of same type as your parameter base_db;

```
DECLARE @base_db_add(VARCHAR(500));
SET @base_db_mdf = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\' +   @dsource + '.mdf' ;
```

And when using it,

```
MOVE 'base_db' TO @base_db_mdf
```

And the same goes for the second one.